# Android Last output arraylist not clear after arraylist.add in looping

Tags: android, arraylist

I wanna ask how to clear last output when add new value of arraylist with loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sqlitealamat.size(); i ++) {

    if (sqlitefirstnext.get(i).trim().equals("0")) {
        sqlitealamat1.add(sqlitealamat.get(i));
        sqliteaddcaption1.add(sqliteaddcaption.get(i));
        sqlitetanggalan1.add(sqlitetanggalan.get(i));
        sqlitelatitudes1.add(sqlitelatitudes.get(i));
        sqlitelongitudes1.add(sqlitelongitudes.get(i));
        sqliteuploadnumber1.add(sqliteuploadnumber.get(i));
        sqlitenik1.add(sqlitenik.get(i));
        sqlitehelpdeskid1.add(sqlitehelpdeskid.get(i));
        sqlitesiteid1.add(sqlitesiteid.get(i));
        sqlitesitename1.add(sqlitesitename.get(i));
        sqlitedescription1.add(sqlitedescription.get(i));
        sqliteremark1.add(sqliteremark.get(i));
        sqliteaddress1.add(sqliteaddress.get(i));
        sqliteworkid1.add(sqliteworkid.get(i));
        sqlitesend1.add(sqlitesend.get(i));
    } else if (sqlitefirstnext.get(i).trim().equals("1")) {
        sqlitealamat2.add(sqlitealamat.get(i));
        sqliteaddcaption2.add(sqliteaddcaption.get(i));
        sqlitetanggalan2.add(sqlitetanggalan.get(i));
        sqlitelatitudes2.add(sqlitelatitudes.get(i));
        sqlitelongitudes2.add(sqlitelongitudes.get(i));
        sqliteuploadnumber2.add(sqliteuploadnumber.get(i));
        sqlitenik2.add(sqlitenik.get(i));
        sqlitehelpdeskid2.add(sqlitehelpdeskid.get(i));
        sqlitesiteid2.add(sqlitesiteid.get(i));
        sqlitesitename2.add(sqlitesitename.get(i));
        sqlitedescription2.add(sqlitedescription.get(i));
        sqliteremark2.add(sqliteremark.get(i));
        sqliteaddress2.add(sqliteaddress.get(i));
        sqliteworkid2.add(sqliteworkid.get(i));
        sqlitesend2.add(sqlitesend.get(i));
    }
}

int size = sqlitealamat2.size();

for (int i = 0; i < sqlitealamat2.size(); i++) {
    Log.i("FIRSTNEXT1", ""+ sqlitealamat2.size());
}
```

example if input 1 new values will show in logcat like this :

```
2917-2917/tmg.tmg I/FIRSTNEXT1﹕ 1
```

and if input another 1 new values :

```
2917-2917/tmg.tmg I/FIRSTNEXT1﹕ 1
2917-2917/tmg.tmg I/FIRSTNEXT1﹕ 2
```

how to show only new output and clear previous output every add new value ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear arraylist before adding new data.
for example `arraylist.clear();`

Clear function clears all the previous data.

Comment: thanks for reply
its not working, i already put list.clear before adding new value

Answer (score 0):

before add in arraylist you need to check

if(arraylist.size>0)`arraylist.clear();`
arraylist.add(new value);`

Answer (score 0):

i didn't see any clear(); command for arraylist in your code before adding values to sqlitealamat2